# C# how does this code work?

Tags: c#, sql

```
Public class form1
{
    List<Data> dataInfo = new List<Data>(); 

    private void UpdateBinding()
    {
        supplierBox.DataSource = dataInfo;
        supplierBox.DisplayMember = "Supplier";         
    }
}
```

I have another class called `Data`:

```
public  class Data
{
    public string Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

This is able to update my textBox named supplier on Visual Studio with data from my SQL Server that I have grabbed. How would I access the data from my SQL Server if I just wanted to put it in a variable like var?

Comment: What problem are you having? You already have your data in a variable (`dataInfo`). Are you having problems accessing this variable elsewhere in code? I assume the problem isn't that you don't know how to create a local variable with var...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
supplier.Text = dataInfo.FirstOrDefault().Supplier;
```

would place the first element from your list of suppliers into your text box named "suppliers". If you don't have any items in your list of dataInfo then you would get a NullReferenceException.